# Making a simple function in R

Tags: r, function

```
x<-sample(0:1,20,TRUE)

predict <- function(x,k){
  n <- length(x)
  k2 <- k/2
  pred<-vector(length=n-k)
  csx<-c(0,cumsum(x))
  for (i in 1:(n-k)){
    pred[i] <-ifelse(csx[i+k]-csx[i] >= k2,1,0)
  }
  return(mean(abs(pred-x[(k+1):n])))
}
```

This code works when I type single number to k.

```
predict(x,2)
```

But I want to set k as range 1 to length(x)/2 which is 1:10 in this case.
And make this into a one function. So that when I just simply type `predict(x,k)`, results will be `predict(x,1) predict(x,2), .. predict(x,length(x)/2)`

How can I do this?

---

I am more used to Python so I tried adding this at the last line which didn't work

```
for (i in range(1:length(x)/2)) predict(x,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend not overwriting the stats::predict function.

Just piggybacking off your Pythonic example, in R you would type:

```
z <- numeric()  # create empty vector to store results
for (i in 1:(length(x)/2)) {z <- c(z,predict(x, i))}
print(z)  # print results to console
```

If you want to wrap that into a function it would look something like this.

```
my_prediction <- function(x){
    z <- numeric()
    for (i in 1:(length(x)/2)) {z <- c(z,predict(x, i))}
    return(z)
}

print(my_prediction(x))
```

If you want to improve performance, you would have to figure out a way to do this without a for-loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see your answer works but is there way I could make that also as a function?